# how to print finite number of digits USING the scientific notation

Tags: python

I have some values that I need to print in scientific notation (values of the order of 10^-8, -9)
But I would like to don't print a long number, only two digits after the .

something as:

`9.84e-08`

and not

`9.84389879870496809597e-08`

How can I do it? I tried to use 
     `"%.2f" % a`
where 'a' is the number containing the value but these numbers appear as `0.00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this :

`print "%.2e"%9.84389879870496809597e-08 #'9.84e-08'`

Answer (score 2):

This works with `format` function of the string (as `%` may be soon deprecated)

```
>>> n
9.843898798704968e-08
>>> print ("{0:.2e}".format(n))
9.84e-08
```

Answer (score 0):

*%f* stands for Fixed Point and will force the number to show relative to the number 1 (1e-3 is shown as 0.001). *%e* stands for Exponential Notation and will give you what you want (1e-3 is shown as 1e-3).